# Browse service as https in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS.
When I select the application where this service resides I can browse it both as `http` and `https` (in *Feature View*):

[image]

But when I select specific service in *Content View*

[image]

the only option available is Browse:

[image]

This Browse defaults to `http`.

Is there any way to set it up to use `https`? It's annoying to change it manually in browser each time.

IIS version is `8.0`.
OS is `Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've found the answer.

It is **Bindings** that rules the behavior of this Browse button.

My solution was to edit site bindings so that `https` lies at the top:
[image]

The same can also be edited in applicationHost file.